# parsley should add a class to a input field

Tags: javascript, validation, parsley.js

is it possible that parsleyjs adds a class (class="error") to the input field that is missing input data? the goal is that the input field gets an red border.

I included parsley for form-validation and it works. Now the error-message seems not enough, they want a red border around the input-field where the user should enter some data. i prepared a class (error) which highlights the input field with a red border if it is added as class to the input field.

Comment: You can use `parsley-error` class instead. Or add some configuration http://parsleyjs.org/documentation.html#parsleyclasses

Comment: thanks, didn't expect it to be this easy